# How to set the input parameter for a stored procedure as not null. The input parameter is clob type

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I want to set a clob as input parameter for db2. How can i specify it as not null while declaring the stored procedure

Comment: What is the reason for you to want that? It's usually better to describe your goal than your failing approach to reach that goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An input parameter of a stored procedure cannot be defined as mandatory in the declaration, so it is up to the developer to validate the input parameter(s) via code in the body of the procedure.